# Visualforce Formula and Apex:repeat

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have some conditionals in my Visualforce page (that will turn into a PDF) but it does not seem to understand the person variable or the `.includes()` function. Is this because formula can not read the `apex:repeat`?

Controller:

```
public User [] hilightName {get;set;}
hilightName = [SELECT Manager.Name FROM User];
```

VF:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!allPeople}" var="person">
<tr>
    <td style="{!IF(person.Name == person.Manager.Name,'background-color: #F78D2C', '')}">{!person.Name}</td> 
    <!--<td style="{!IF(hilightName.includes(person.Name),'background-color: #F78D2C', '')}">{!person.Name}</td>--> 
    <td>{!person.Phone}</td>
    <td>{!person.Extension}</td>
    <td>{!person.Title}</td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

UPDATE:
I was using contains/includes wrong.

```
<td style="{!IF(contains(person.Name,person.Manager.Name),'background-color: #efefef', '')}">{!person.Name}</td>
```

Comment: That's no JavaScript, it's a Visualforce formula.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you for the correct naming. I just always call it inline conditionals which makes me think of JavaScript. I updated the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` function of String class is available in Javascript.

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.includes("world");
```

In Visualforce `<apex:repeat/>` in that `<td/>` use formula expression like

`"{!(CONTAINS(hilightName,person.Name))}"`

For more information, refer [Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)